# Wget changing character around download location

Tags: perl, wget, handle

I have a little perl script that I updated to download images from tvrage. But I have a problem.
This is the code line I have problems with:

```
system "wget -P '/home/user/script/cache/posters' $imgurl";
```

It usually works just fine but from time to time it fails with the same error.

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 16758 (16K) [image/jpeg]
Saving to: â/home/user/script/cache/posters/28386.jpgâ
ERROR! Wide character in syswrite at IO/Handle.pm line 207.
ERROR! Wide character in syswrite at IO/Handle.pm line 207.
Compilation failed in require.
Wide character in syswrite at IO/
```

I have located the problem to be that wget changes ‘ and ’ to â

â/home/user/script/cache/posters/28386.jpgâ

All successful downloads have the ‘ and ’

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 28218 (28K) [image/jpeg]
Saving to: ‘/home/user/script/cache/posters/6597.jpg’
```

I just tried adding this

```
system "wget --restrict-file-names=nocontrol -P '/home/tup/tuper4/cache/posters' $imgurl";
```

In the hope that it would work better and so far it has not failed but I suspect it's not the issue and would like some guidance if possible.

Should I maybe try

```
system "cd /location/ && wget $imgurl";
```

Would it make any difference?

I guess my real question here is: What could cause wget to change from ‘ and ’ to â ?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Output of locale is:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

And the images are also UTF-8

I did suspect that it had to do with the encoding and hence added

```
--restrict-file-names=nocontrol
```

Remains to see if it will work.

Edit: Several days later and I have not seen the error again so it looks like "nocontrol" helped.

Answer (score 0):

It's not `wget` changing the character.
The character encoding seems to be set to something wrong.

When the real encoding is `UTF-8`, as it probably is, but set to something else, showing the quote as character `â` is a typical symptom. Sometimes it's followed by more characters.

So it should work if you set the encoding to `UTF-8`.

--

What is the output of the command `locale`?

Background info:
http://askleo.com/why_do_i_get_odd_characters_instead_of_quotes_in_my_documents/

Googling "â quote" gives some good results.

Comment: Output of locale is:
`LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=`

Comment: Oh, locale looks right... Does it work if you just do it again a couple of times after the error? Does it work when you run the same command from the shell?

Comment: It fails sometimes, you say. Is it changing for the same url? Can you give a test case, an url where the error occurs?

Comment: Unfortunately the way the script works you cant repeat same exact download. The script is running on a clients server and I dont have as much freedom to run tests as I would like to. I simply have to wait and see if it fails again.

Comment: This works fine: http://images.tvrage.com/shows/46/45115.jpg This failed: http://images.tvrage.com/shows/29/28386.jpg

Comment: Hmm.. the I'd like to see the `locale` on that machine, of course. And that's where the encoding needs to be set. As an alternative guess, it may be related to an encoding HTTP header - you could add `--server-response` to the `wget` options.

Comment: If it fails again I will try the --server-response

Comment: Maybe also add `--debug`.